# Host laravel on public_html and avoid people to access files

Tags: php, laravel

My host don't allow me to create directories outside `public_html` so I have to place all my Laravel project there, is there any way to prevent people access my files?

Comment: Get a better host and if that is not a possibility you will have to look into htaccess.

Comment: you know any free host that I can have directories outside public_html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes that is possible. You have to create a .htaccess file for your directories that you want to prevent public access. Inside that directory just add this line

```
deny from all
```

With this you can include the php files in your codes but from outside others cannot access it.